# Switch statement error in C++

Tags: c++

Hello guys would someone please help me to fix this code of mine? It runs but it  doesn't perform the task it should do. Once you run it, it automatically jumps in to the default statement and skips the cases. Please help me fix this thanks!

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int choice;
    char nbaPlayer, tele, food, subject, x;

    cout << "This program determines your favorites.\n\n";
    cout << "Please select the number of your corresponding choice.";
    cout << "\n1. NBA Player";
    cout << "\n2. Teleserye";
    cout << "\n3. Food";
    cout << "\n4. Subject";
    cout << "\n5. Exit";

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << "You have chosen NBA Player.\n";
            cout << "Please enter your favorite NBA Player. \n";
            cin >> nbaPlayer;
            cout << "Your favorite NBA player is " << nbaPlayer;
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "You have chosen Teleserye.\n";
            cout << "Please enter your favorite teleserye. \n";
            cin >> tele;
            cout << "Your favorite teleserye is " << tele;
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "You have chosen food.\n";
            cout << "Please enter your favorite food. \n";
            cin >> food;
            cout << "Your favorite food is " << food;
            break;

        case 4:
            cout << "You have chosen subject.\n";
            cout << "Please enter your favorite subject. \n";
            cin >> subject;
            cout << "Your favorite subject is " << subject;
            break;

        case 5:
            cout << "You chose to exit.\n";
            break;

        default:
            cout <<"\nInvalid input";

    }

    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You simply forgot:

```
cin>>choice
```

after you display available choice options. So when you never assign value to choice, it'll always choose `default`.

Comment: Small correction: it will not always chose `default`. It is undefined behaviour to read from an uninitialized `int`. In practice, `choice` could have any value.